# How to find centers of two circle when their intersecting points and corresponding radius is given?

Tags: geometry

I was reading chapter 7 of "Competitive Programming 3" by Steven and Felix Halim. I then found this problem, given in picture:

[image]

Here two intersecting points of two circles and corresponding radius are also given. I have to find centres of two circles. They have given the solution code. But I didn't understand the technique behind it. The given code is:

[image]

I have searched many times, but I didn't find. Can anyone explain the technique?

Anyway, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first visualize variables `d2` and `h` defined in the code:
[image]

As we can see, `d2` stands for the square of the distance between `p1` and `p2`. Let's put `d = sqrt(d2)`. Then `d^2 = d2`.

Using Pythagoras: `r^2 = h^2 + d^2/4`. Hence, `h^2 = r^2 - d^2/4`.

The unitary (norm = `1`) vector in the direction of the line joining `p1` and `p2` is:

```
v := (p2 - p1)/d = (p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y)/d.
```

its perpendicular is

```
w := (p2.y - p1.y, p1.x - p2.x)/d
```

Now we can express `c1` as a point in the perpendicular direction:

```
c1 = q + w*h = (p1 + p2)/2 + w*h,
```

because `w` has norm `1` and `h` is precisely the distance between `c1` and `q`. Therefore,

```
c1 = (p1.x + p2.x, p1.y + p2.y)/2 + (p2.y - p1.y, p1.x - p2.x)*h/d
```

where

```
h/d = sqrt(r^2 - d^2/4)/d = sqrt(r^2/d2 - 1/4)
```

which explains the code.

---

**Notes**

1. From the picture that `r` is always `ge` than `d/2`. Thus, `r^2 ≥ d^2/4` or `(r/d)^2 ≥ 1/4` and there is no need to check whether `det < 0`, because it never is (provided the circles intersect).
2. The derivation above will actually produce two solutions for `c1`, one to the right of the blue line from `p1` to `p2`, which is the one in the drawing, and another on the left of said line. In fact, these correspond to the equations

   ```
   c1 = q ± w*h = q + w*(±h)
   ```

   In order to decide whether we should use `+h` or `-h`, we can apply one of the well-known criteria for establishing whether a point lies on the left or the right of a directed segment. For example, we could compute the sign of the determinant

   ```
        | 1 p1.x p1.y |
    D = | 1 p2.x p2.y | = (p2.x-p1.x)(c1.y-p1.y) - (p2.y-p1.y)(c1.x-p1.x)
        | 1 c1.x c1.y |
   ```

which will have a sign for `+h` and the opposite for `-h`. The value of `h` that makes `D < 0` is the one that leaves `c1` on the right of the segment from `p1` to `p2`.

---

Comment: Nice explanation. But I have one question. c1 = q + wh or, c1 = q - wh ? which one is correct?

Another question, must I need the radius of the second circle to get the center of the second circle?

Comment: Good question. See my second note (let me think your second question...)

Comment: Yes, you need the radius of the second circle. The reason is that otherwise you would only know two of its points, namely `p1` and `p2`, and you need three points to determine a circle. Therefore without further information (say, the radius) there would be infinite circles (centers) with the same intersection points.

Comment: I have understood your answer. Very well explanation. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Apply Pythagoras in the right triangles. This gives you the distances between the midpoint of p1p2 and the centers.

From unit vectors parallel then orthogonal to p1p2, the offset vectors are easily obtained.

Comment: Would you please explain mathematically? It will be helpful for me :)